# My Firebase Database returns null for each Member properties

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a Firebase database to store members just like contacts, am trying to fetch all the members properties stored in the database. Now the list of members is fetching correctly but the member details e.g the `phone`, `email` etc return `null`. Please help me out.

This the Firebase database structure:

[image: Firebase database Structure]

This is my code to fetch the list of members:

```
members = new ArrayList<>();
    member = new Member();
    adapter = new AllMembersAdapter(members, this);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = database.getReference().child("Rad5 Tech Hub");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            members.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                member = ds.getValue(Member.class);
                Log.d("debugger", "member email: " + member.getEmail()); //returns null
                members.add(member);

            }

            recyclerViewList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is my Member Class

```
public class Member {

private String mMonthName;
private String mLastName;
private String mGender;
private String mEmail;
private String mPhone;
private String mAddress;
private String mDate;
private String mOccupation;

public Member(){}

public Member(String mAddress, String mDate, String mEmail, String mGender,
              String mLastName, String mMonthName, String mOccupation, String mPhone) {
    this.mLastName = mLastName;
    this.mGender = mGender;
    this.mEmail = mEmail;
    this.mPhone = mPhone;
    this.mAddress = mAddress;
    this.mDate = mDate;
    this.mOccupation = mOccupation;
    this.mMonthName = mMonthName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return mLastName;
}

public String getGender() {
    return mGender;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return mEmail;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return mPhone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return mAddress;
}

public String getDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public String getMonthName() {
    return mMonthName;
}

public String getOccupation() {
    return mOccupation;
}

public Map<String, Object> toMap(){
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("address", mAddress);
    result.put("birthday", mDate);
    result.put("email", mEmail);
    result.put("gender", mGender);
    result.put("last name", mLastName);
    result.put("month name", mMonthName);
    result.put("occupation", mOccupation);
    result.put("phone number", mPhone);

    return result;
}
```

}

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class AllMembersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllMembersAdapter.MembersViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Member> members;
ListItemClickListener listItemClickListener;

public AllMembersAdapter(ArrayList<Member> members, ListItemClickListener listItemClickListener) {
    this.members = members;
    this.listItemClickListener = listItemClickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MembersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.member_item, parent, false);
    return new MembersViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MembersViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Member member = members.get(position);
    String _monthName = member.getMonthName();

    holder.mMonth.setText(_monthName);
    holder.mName.setText(member.getLastName());
    holder.mDate.setText(member.getDate());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return members.size();
}

public interface ListItemClickListener{
    void onListItemClick(int position);
}

public class MembersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView mMonth;
    TextView mName;
    TextView mDate;

    public MembersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mMonth = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_month);
        mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        mDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listItemClickListener.onListItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *Member* class fields should have the same names as firebase fields that you want to retrieve. 
So instead of naming the parameter `mEmail` it should be `email`. Btw Java field names can't have whitespace so please replace all your firebase field whitespaces with underscores. 
Example: `month name` -> `month_name` or even better `monthName`

Then update field names in your *Member* class to match firebase fields.

Comment: Thanks a million the problem was solved with the changes

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 3):

As @TheTechWolf mentioned in his comment, the problem is that `Member` class fields are different then the names of the fields that you have in your Firebase database. Let's take an example, in your model class you have a field named `mMonthName` but in the database the corresponding field is named `month name`. When you are using a getter named `getMonthName()`, Firebase is looking after a field named `monthName` and not `mMonthName` as you have now. So to solve this, please use the following model class which contains all member fields that you need:

```
public class Member {
    private String monthName, lastName, gender, email, phone, address, date, occupation;

    public Member() {}

    public Member(String monthName, String lastName, String gender, String email, String phone, String address, String date, String occupation) {
        this.monthName = monthName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.date = date;
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public String getMonthName() { return monthName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public String getGender() { return gender; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public String getPhone() { return phone; }
    public String getAddress() { return address; }
    public String getDate() { return date; }
    public String getOccupation() { return occupation; }
}
```